# Equivalent of "Optional" (maybe type) from Java in Powershell

Tags: powershell, option-type

Citing wikipedia:

> In programming languages (especially functional programming languages)
> and type theory, an option type or maybe type is a polymorphic type
> that represents encapsulation of an optional value; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_type

Code from the method where I would like to put the Optional is:

```
function FindElement {

 if ($element -ne $null) {
        $valueFromXml =   $element.InnerText
        Write-Information "valueFromXml found in   xml: $valueFromXml "
        return  $valueFromXml

    } else {
        Write-Information "valueFromXml  not found."
        return null #I do not like to return null, need to refactor that
    }
}
```

I am using Optional<> Type in Java very often but I am not able to find anything like that in PowerShell. Is there any structure in Powershell which provides same functionality? How to use it in my code at lines:

```
 return  $valueFromXml
```

and

```
return null
```

And how to handle the return value after calling the method FindElement ?

Comment: It's `$null`, not `null`. What is it specifically you "do not like" about returning it?

Comment: You don’t even really have to return *anything* - ```function x { if( $myBool ) { write-host "look at this!"; return $true } else { write-host "nothing to see here" } }: $y = x; write-host ($null -eq $y)```. PowerShell is primarily a *scripting* language, and the rules for those are typically looser than compiled strongly-typed languages - learn to embrace the brevity and don’t worry *too* much about writing strict C# / Java-style programs in Powershell :-).

Comment: Also, when you *are* comparing to ```$null``` make sure you put it on the *left* of the operator - e.g. ```$null -eq $element``` to avoid unexpected behaviour if ```$element``` happens to be a collection type… https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/utility-modules/psscriptanalyzer/rules/possibleincorrectcomparisonwithnull?view=ps-modules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: replaced `exit` with `return` as of @mclayton's suggestion

SCRIPT IMPROVEMENT

```
function FindElement {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        $Element
    )
    process {
        # if null, writes it to the Information Stream and exits the function altogether
        if ($null -eq $Element) {
            Write-Information 'valueFromXml  not found.'
            return
        }
            
        # No need for `else`: it's never going to reach here unless $Element is not null
        $valueFromXml = $element.InnerText
        Write-Information "valueFromXml found in   xml: $valueFromXml "
        return  $valueFromXml

    }
}
```

--

```
PS > $Var = FindElement -Element $null
PS > $null -eq $Var
True
```

OLD ANSWER

Sure, it's [Nullable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable)
Usually powershell converts `$Null` assignments to whatever is the empty value default of the class of the variable. `[int]$null` returns `0` for example.

But `[System.Nullable[int]]$null` returns `$null`

Comment: I have updated my answer with a piece of  code. Could you advise how I could rewrite my code to include this $Null ? And how Can I handle it later?

Comment: Honestly your function does not need to return $Null explicitly: a function that does not return anything is the same as returning $null.     

I modified my answer with a example of code

Comment: I would suggest using ```return``` on its own rather than ```exit``` in your function - the latter terminates the entire script or session (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_language_keywords?view=powershell-7.4#exit) whereas ```return``` just exits the current function and returns control to the caller, which is a much more common scenario…

Comment: I would like to use this function from another function in a fluent way. According to functional programming paradigms